# javafx best way to make detailed TableView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, tableview, javafx-8

I'm currently writing an application that manages some time slots for "projects".

What it should look like:

[image: Quickly created with LibreOffice :D]

Now I have the Problem that the JavaFX TableView does not support Colum *AND* Row description..

I have the Data as following:

I've got an `ObservableList<Project>`
Every Project has an `ObservableMap<Date, ObservableList<Person>>`

How can I create the TableView with this data?

I googled and found these options:

- create a normal grid an manage it over listeners
- Make a TableView and the Columns still Dates --> every Cell is a VBox of Persons

**Isn't there a better way? E.g. some hidden feature I have yet not found with the CellFactory**

Comment: How about using third-party controls i.e. [SpreadsheetView](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#spreadsheetview) from ControlsFX library?

Comment: I try to not use any external libraries if I only need one or two things. I wrote a custom `GridPane` that fits my needs. Maybe I'll upload it to Github some time. Thanks anyway for answering :)